# How to use super() on Alloy Controller Inheritance

Tags: appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy

How do you call the anchestor function on a child, like using keyword **super** in Java.

**parent.js**

```
exports.test = function(){
  Ti.API.info('Parent Function');
}
```

**child.js**

```
exports.baseController = 'parent';

exports.test = function() {
  // super.test(); <-- should print "Parent Function"
  Ti.API.info('Child Overriden Function');
}
```

Appcelerator Alloy Inheritance : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Inheritance

Answer (score 0):

Use this. instead of super.

```
this.test();
```

Comment: Using this on the child function will actually cause an infinite recursion loop

Comment: just in case anyone drops by looking for the answer use  `$.test()`